# Swift: Edit color of icons in "Edit" page in "More" tab of UITabBar

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I would like to change the color of the icons in the "edit" tab located in the "more" section of a UITabBar. 
I have already changed the color of the icons in the "more" tab by

```
tabBarController!.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
if let moreTableView = tabBarController!.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view as? UITableView {
    moreTableView.tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

But the "Edit" button in the top-right opens a page where all the icons are still the default blue (with the exception of the gray selected icons). I would like to change this to red programmatically (in swift) but I don't know how. All the questions and answers that I looked up deal with the "more" tab and not the "edit" page of the "more" tab.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Here are some images of what I would like to do:
[image]
That is what I already did, and all the other questions on SO. What I would like is for the below image to be red (the color shown is close enough to red; the specific color is not an issue) rather than the blue tint.
[image]

Comment: Can you show the image ?

Comment: I added some images in the edit. Thanks for the suggestion!